# Why are events not firing like onkeyup, onkeypress, onmouseup?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here is a jsfiddle example of what I am working on:
http://jsfiddle.net/bdijVd/2/.  
Why don't the text fields update?

Comment: Post a sample of your **representative code** in your **question**, both JavaScript **and** your html.

Comment: Why and when would the text fields update? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome, the events work but you see nothing because of the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'getBrowser'`

Thrown on line 38:

`document.getElementById('txtarea').innerHTML = ("<b>" + tagline + "</b>" + "</br >" + "<br />" + "<i>" + "<u>" + author + " " + date + "." + "</u> " + author + " (" + credentials + ") " + date + " " + publication + " " + title + " " + (window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href) + "</i>" + "<br />" + "<br />" + evidence);`

Comment: And just to follow up, if you change that line to `document.getElementById('txtarea').innerHTML = ("<b>" + tagline + "</b>" + "</br >" + "<br />" + "<i>" + "<u>" + author + " " + date + "." + "</u> " + author + " (" + credentials + ") " + date + " " + publication + " " + title + " " + (window.location.href) + "</i>" + "<br />" + "<br />" + evidence);`, it looks like you're in business -- http://jsfiddle.net/bdjVd/6/

Answer (score 2):

In FireFox, your `format()` function is throwing the error `Permission denied to access property 'getBrowser'`.